# Difference in fmin_l_bfgs_b implemented in MATLAB and Scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy, autoencoder

I was following the Sparse Autoencoder tutorial in the Stanford UFLDL series (http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Exercise:Sparse_Autoencoder).

I finished the MATLAB version of implementation and it works perfectly fine, but I noticed some discrepancies when ported the **same** implementation to Python (with numpy, scipy, and Matplotlib).

I noticed that the cost function were not minimized to the same magnitude. I am aware that due to the fact thetas are randomly initialized, each run will give different final cost values, but after rerunning both implementations for 20+ times, I always see the Python implementation resulting *f_cost = 4.57e-1* while the MATLAB version gives answers around *f_cost = 4.46e-1*. In other words, there is a consistent difference of *~0.01*.

Since these are two implementations identical in theory (same cost func, same gradient, same minFunc, LBFGS)

Since I suspect the problem is conditional on the cost function and gradient computation, I could not reproduce it in a few lines. But you can find the full code in Python and MATLAB on Github (https://github.com/alanhyue/cs294a_2011-sparseAutoencoders).

#### Additional details

Here are a few more details that might help clarify the problem.

1. LBFGS and LBFGS-B
   The starter code provided by the tutorial uses LBFGS to minimize thetas, while I did not find the exact equivalent in Scipy, I am using the scipy.optimize.fmin_l_bfgs_b. I read on Wikipedia that LBFGS-B is a boxed version of LBFGS. I suppose they should give the same result?
2. Both implementations passed numerical gradient checking
   I assume this means the gradient calculation is correct.
3. Results looks *somewhat* correct.
   As indicated in the lecture notes, a correct implementation should get a collection of *line detectors*, which means each patches would look like a picture of a straight line.

Here is the result from Python (with a cost of 0.457). 
[Results of Python implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWPRl.png)

Here is the result from MATLAB (with a cost of 0.446).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWCRI.jpg)